# "Too many requests from this IP address" while attempting to merge accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts, email, rate-limiting, merge-accounts

Let me tell you a story: I want to merge two accounts. I proceeded as explained in [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or OpenID / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist).

**I never received the second confirmation email.** I then filled out the "contact us" form with "other" as the subject, as we are supposed to do in this case, and submitted it.

As I received the first mail on my vanilla Gmail mail and as the second one was supposed to arrived on a non-vanilla mail (a facade mail furnished by a former school of mine, and only redirecting mails to a chosen address), I changed this non-vanilla mail in the second account to another Gmail address, and proceeded again as explained in the aforementioned link.

**Again, I never received the second confirmation email.** Then I filled out the "contact us" again, as we are supposed to do in this case, and when I submitted, I received a **"We have detected too many requests from this IP, try tomorrow"** error (or something like that).

It is frustrating. Why did this happen and how should I proceed?

**Small - frustrating - update** (while not answer from the support) :

[image: Email from Stack Exchange]

Of course, the second mail got the same irratating email. While still no answer from support. Thx.

Comment: @jason-c Why did you replace "Superb" by "It's frustrating. Why did this happen and how should I proceed?" as it is by all means clear for eveyone that it is what it means ?

Comment: You're welcome to change it back; I thought I'd mellow out the tone a little bit, that's all. :)

Comment: Agree with @Jason, this made it less a rant and more a valid support question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your IP was never blocked or rate limited from accessing the site, I'm guessing you encountered the help center rate limit. Unless you go through one of the automated systems, you can only submit one request to the support team per day (I don't know the exact criteria for how it determines whether you've submitted one today or not, but it isn't always based on IP).

You already submitted an "other" request for further help with your merge. There's no reason to submit another request, and this check was implemented explicitly to prevent our queues getting flooded with duplicate tickets from people who just keep submitting the contact form over and over until they get a response. You'll need to just wait for a reply to your existing ticket.

Comment: Even if in the meantime I change the mail of the second account ?

Comment: If resubmissions are a problem then it might help to tell people how long they typically have to wait.  I recall the word "shortly" being used in the confirmation page for my own submission, which in my mind set an expectation well short of 24 hours.